# ASSERT fails on CDC SelectObject() call - What can I try?

Tags: c++, mfc, assert

I'm working on a multi-threaded win32 MFC application.  We are rendering a map and displaying it in a pane in the user interface along with custom-rendered objects on top.  It's slow to render (~800 ms), which is happening on the User Interface thread.

I'm trying to move the rendering onto its own thread so that the menus still remain snappy while the other rendering can still run in the background.  The Draw thread will render continually using its own CDC.  The UI thread will call a redraw function, which locks the mutex, and takes the last snapshot of the `CBitmap` and draws it using the UI's `CDC`.  Every location where the Draw thread's `CD`C is used, is locked by the mutex.

What I'm seeing is the thread creating a new `CBitmap` via `CreatCompatibleBitmap`, and then trying to select the new `CBitmap` object into the Draw thread's `CDC`.

```
this->m_canvas.CreateCompatibleDC(&compatibleDC);
this->m_bitmap = new CBitmap();
this->m_bitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(&compatibleDC, m_width, m_height);

m_oldBitmap = this->m_canvas.SelectObject(m_bitmap);
```

At this point, there is a debug ASSERT failure in CGdiObject::FromHandle().

```
CGdiObject* PASCAL CGdiObject::FromHandle(HGDIOBJ h)
{
    CHandleMap* pMap = afxMapHGDIOBJ(TRUE); //create map if not exist
    ASSERT(pMap != NULL);
    CGdiObject* pObject = (CGdiObject*)pMap->FromHandle(h);
    ASSERT(pObject == NULL || pObject->m_hObject == h);
    return pObject;
}
```

The second `ASSERT` is failing because the `m_hObject` does not match the handle passed in.  Basically, MFC is taking the handle, and doing a lookup to get a `CBitmap` object which somehow doesn't match the `CBitmap` that was just created.

Does this sound familiar to anyone?  What could be happening to cause the `FromHandle` method to return the wrong object?  Is there a fundamental flaw with the way I create a `CDC` for the Draw thread, and then re-use it over and over?  Are there any approaches I can take to help debug/fix this problem?

Comment: That's definitely odd: by the time you're in CGdiObject::FromHandle() we're handling the return value from ::SelectObject(), and it's not obvious how that could go wrong. Does pObject look like a valid object when the assert happens?

Comment: Yes. pObject is valid, and a CBitmap... but not the same CBitmap constructed in the 'new Bitmap()' statement.

Comment: There's one handle->object lookup map for each thread... I was creating the CBitmap in one thread, then trying to use it in the other... the lookup in the map was failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golden.  The mapping between handles and objects are in [thread-local storage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/147578/EN-US/).

> In a multi-threaded environment
>   because windows are owned by threads,
>   MFC keeps the temporary and permanent
>   window handle map in thread local
>   storage. The same is true for other
>   handle maps like those for GDI objects
>   and device contexts. Keeping the
>   window handle maps in thread local
>   storage ensures protection against
>   simultaneous access by several
>   threads.

So basically, store the handle, then create a CBitmap from the handle in order to manipulate them between threads.

My mistake was in the UI thread creating my CBitmap, and then accessing the CBitmap object from both threads.

Comment: Heh.  Made exactly the same mistake moving draw code into its own thread for exactly the same reasons.  Got some good answers and references asking a similar question which may be of value; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287114/thread-type-for-background-drawing-to-a-bitmap-in-mfc

Comment: Can you show an example of how you stored the Handle?

Comment: It was MFC that was storing the Handle as part of the CBitmap implementation.  If there's something specific you're looking for with Handles or thread-local storage, ask a new question to get more people helping!